# Forward with URL masking is breaking the css for a site built with react gatsby and hosted on netlify

Tags: url-masking, domain-masking

I have a site built on **Gatsby JS (React)** and whenever I forward a subdomain with masking the css for mobile breaks.
My domain registrar is godaddy and forward without masking works

For example:

```
abc.mydomain.com -> mysite.netlify.com (No Masking) ->Responsive
abc.mydomain.com -> mysite.netlify.com (Masking) -> No responsiveness
```

Any help is appreciated!